# WooCommerce Email Inquiry and Cart Options plugin can not be activated

Tags: plugins, woocommerce

I got the latest version of this beautiful plugin call: WooCommerce Email Inquiry and Cart Options Pro, but It **needs to be activated after installation also It needs to be bound with one domain name**, this is not good.

Dear friend could you pls help me to solve these two problem? [This is the plugin download address](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/he1gzhip9gfq4aa/AAA0Gr5hmIicFow4gCptYaoxa?dl=0).

Error pagek: 
[image]

Comment: what you are asking is unclear. If you want to activate the plugin then you need to purchase it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this plugin but you should reaching out to the developers of the plugin here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-email-inquiry-cart-options/

Keys are typically used to validate a purchase.